# HTML Labels Issue

Tags: html, css

I have an issue on my custom labels.

```css
.label-ras{
    padding:3px 10px;
    line-height:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:400;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:75%;
    
}
.label-primar{background-color:#5c4ac7}
```

```html
<span style="background-color: #f25a04" class="label-ras label-primar"> <i style="color: white; font-size: 11px;" class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Fondator</span><br>
<span style="background-color: #f25a04" class="label-ras label-primar"> <i style="color: white; font-size: 11px;" class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Fondator</span><br>
```

As you can see, these two labels are are glued.
I want to be a little space between these two labels.

Comment: So add margin??

Comment: You can give me an example ? @epascarello

Comment: Set to block or inline block and set the margin.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding margin and display inline-block to .label-ras class as follows-

```css
.label-ras{
    padding:3px 10px;
    line-height:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:400;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-size:75%;
    margin:5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the display to block or inline-block and add a **[margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)**:

```css
.label-ras {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.label-primar {
  background-color: #5c4ac7
}
```

```html
<span style="background-color: #f25a04" class="label-ras label-primar"> <i style="color: white; font-size: 11px;" class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Fondator</span><br>
<span style="background-color: #f25a04" class="label-ras label-primar"> <i style="color: white; font-size: 11px;" class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Fondator</span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it
`span.labal-primar:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 12px; }`

It will add right margin space to every `span.label-primar` element except the last one. Now, no matter you have 2 spans or 10 or 100.
Keep in mind, you have to assign your `span` to `display: inline-block` to work with margins.